# Some icons do not appear in my project in react-native projects

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-vector-icons in my project to show some icons. But some icons appear but some icons do not appear. I upgradeded the version of the react-native-vector-icons but it did not work. Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you please share detailed info about which icons get displayed and which not? It will be good if you share some code.

Comment: For example, the icon that was specified by its name did not appear in my project. <Icon name={'directions_walk'} color={'black'} size={40} /> It is just simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is it just a typo or did you write the icon name wrong?

[Here](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/) you can see it's `directions-walk`, not `directions_walk`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: oww thank you very much bro. It was a small mistake but it did not happen beacuse of me. I wrote the name of this icon with respect to information in this page https://material.io/tools/icons/ , Maybe the name of the icon I wrote is just valid for web page. It solved my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please accept my answer as the solution?